Select all value except min value and add corresponding min value in another column
Consider this table:



id
text




101
Black


102
Black


103
White


104
White


105
White



How one could select all the ids except the min id, but also add the corresponding min value in another column? So the expected result would look like:



not min
text
min id




102
Black
101


104
White
103


105
White
103



I'm using SQL Server 2019 (v15.x).

You may use windowed MIN:
SELECT *
FROM (  
   SELECT [id], [text], [min id] = MIN([id]) OVER (PARTITION BY [text] ORDER BY [id])
   FROM Data
) t
WHERE [id] <> [min id]


You can try using subquery with join.
SELECT 
    T1.id 'not min', 
    T1.color, 
    T2.min_id 
FROM 
    TEST T1
JOIN 
    (SELECT color, MIN(id) min_id FROM TEST GROUP BY color) T2 
    ON T1.color = T2.color
WHERE 
    T1.id != T2.min_id;


WITH MinIDs AS
        (
                SELECT
                        MIN(id) AS MinID,
                        text
                FROM
                        TableName
                GROUP BY
                        text )
SELECT
        t.id AS [not min],
        t.text           ,
        m.MinID AS [min id]
FROM
        TableName t
INNER JOIN
        MinIDs m
ON
        t.text = m.text
WHERE
        t.id != m.MinID

